# Equivalent of MPEG4 GOP in H264?

Tags: h.264

i try to correct a gap detection feature and for this i use the GOP length when decoding mpeg4.

But for H264 i cannot find anything like the keywords that are in the mpeg4 spec:  fixed_vop_rate, fixed_vop_time_increment, vop_time_increment_resolution

Can somebody provide me with a good resource on how to work with GOP length in H264?

Comment: fixed_vop_rate, "fixed_vop_time_increment, vop_time_increment_resolution, has no relation to GOP length, these fiels are more for frame-rate. Do you want to calculate frame-rate or GOP length ?

Comment: Im looking for the GOP length.